# How to setup ssl on Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: ssl, glassfish

Can someone please give me a good guide on how to install a new ssl certificate into glassfish 3.1.2.2. I have been able to generate the csr, with guide from [enter link description here](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/)I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

There is very good official documentation for security in GlassFish. [Here is a link to a PDF](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/pdf/821-2435.pdf) which goes through exactly what you need. Look for page 47 onwards.

The same information is also [available in HTML format here.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/ablqz.html#scrolltoc)